# Sistema de Login php

Tags: php, sql

Ola,

Estou criando um site com sistema de login em php, e estou com o seguinte problema,

Quando Digito o Login ele não verifica no banco de dados se as informações existem.

Queria saber qual erro estou cometendo.

Segue o Código:

```
<p>
    <label for="email">E-mail:</label><br>
    <input required type="text" id="email" name="email" size="35">
</p>


<p>
    <label for="senha">Senha:</label><br>
    <input type="password" id="senha" name="senha" required>
</p>

 <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="enviar">
```

```
    if( empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["senha"]) ){
        echo "Digite o Login";
    }else {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $senha = $_POST['senha'];

        // Verificando se o usuário/e-mail existe no sistema
        $usuarios = buscaUsuario($conexao, $email);



        // Processo de login
                if( password_verify($senha, $usuarios['senha']) ){
                entrar($usuarios['id'],$usuarios['email'],$usuarios['senha']);
                header("location:posts.php");
            } else {
            echo "Login não encontrado";
            }   
    }       
    }
```

Comment: Poderia descrever mais exatamente o que seria _"ele não verifica no banco de dados se as informações existem"_? Já debugou o código pra verificar se os dados recebidos no PHP estão corretos e em qual `if/else`está passando?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas se não me engano, só funcionará se os `inputs` estiverem dentro de um `form` com um `action=` aprontando para um PHP e especificando o `method="Post"` no seu caso...